# How do I create variables for my SQL statement to reference cells in Excel?

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

Newbie here. I have extensive experience with Excel, and I am recently started learning SQL Server 2008 R2 and VBA. I have been asked to create an ODBC call to our ERP database to pull trial balance data into an Excel file.

The SQL script itself was very easy, however, I am trying to find a way to convert the fixed date ranges in my case statements to be variable based on an Excel field.

Following is an excerpt from my SQL script:

```
SELECT
    glmast.fcacctnum, RTRIM(cspopup.fcpoptext) AS Type,
    SUM(CASE 
           WHEN glitem.fddate BETWEEN '07-01-2016' AND '07-31-2016' 
              THEN glitem.fnamount ELSE 0 
        END) AS PY_Jul,
    SUM(CASE 
           WHEN glitem.fddate BETWEEN '07-01-2016' AND '08-31-2016' 
              THEN glitem.fnamount ELSE 0 
        END) AS PY_Aug
    ... **wash rinse repeat** ...
    SUM(CASE 
           WHEN glitem.fddate BETWEEN '07-01-2016' AND '06-30-2017' 
              THEN glitem.fnamount ELSE 0 
        END) AS PY_Jun
FROM
    glmast
INNER JOIN 
    glitem ON glmast.fcacctnum = glitem.fcacctnum
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    cspopup ON glmast.fctype = cspopup.fcpopval
WHERE 
    cspopup.fcpopkey = 'GLMAST.FCTYPE' AND 
    glmast.flinactive = 'False' AND glitem.fcclass <> 'Y' AND 
    glitem.fddate > '06-30-2016'
```

Can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

Of course it can be done.
Just record macro for ODBC procedure in order to get the whole hardcode. and then change the sql part like this.

```
myfddate=InputBox("Enter the date")

sSql = "SELECT ......." & Chr(10) 
sSql = sSql & "......." & Chr(10) 
sSql=  "WHERE ...... and fddate >" & myfddate
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I have two questions: I am not understanding how the Select statement is allowing for variable dates.  I see that the condition parameter is calling for a date field. I have already been able to get that to work by setting the parameter in Microsoft query to refer to a cell.  The challenge I have is how to get the dates in the select statement to refer to a cell in the workbook.  I'm trying to avoid the need to manually change the connection command text every time the file is rolled forward to a new date period.

Comment: ok then, instead of asking the user with inputbox,you could get the value of myfddate from a cell, like-->myfddate=Range("A2").Value

Comment: How would that be represented in the Select statement:  ` ,SUM
 (CASE WHEN glitem.fddate BETWEEN '07-01-2017' AND '07-31-2017' THEN glitem.fnamount ELSE 0  END) AS CY_Jul`

Comment: what do you mean? Have you already created the connection string and did other settings regarding connection?

Comment: Yes. I started this project with Microsoft Query. I have a connection and the Command text. In MQ I can set parameters (the condition WHERE statement) that allow me to refer to a cell in the workbook, but I can not create variable for the SELECT statement...which I excerpted in my last question.  I can establish another connection an input the command string....just need some additional guidance on what that would look like exactly.

Comment: we r not allowed to put variables in the select statements as in programming languages like c# or java. instead we should separate the text  to the variable from text after variable through & characters, as i stated in my first answer

Comment: Apologies but I really don't understand what you are telling me.  I do not have a coding background. Can you show me the specific statement I would use?

Comment: last question: will the dates in between statements be dynamic/parametric, or only the one in where clause?

Comment: The dates in the between statements will be dynamic, as in they will change each fiscal year.  The Where statement is also dynamic and a parameter for the full date range being used to calculate the individual (24) trial balances..

Comment: The only thing i can add for now is as follows.                                                    S1="SELECT glmast.fcacctnum, RTRIM(cspopup.fcpoptext) AS Type, "
S2="SUM(CASE WHEN glitem.fddate BETWEEN " & DateFirst & " AND " & DateSecond
S3="THEN glitem.fnamount ELSE 0 END) AS PY_Jul,"
'other parts of SQL
S20="WHERE  …….    glitem.fddate > " & DateWhere

'other stuff

With ActiveWorkbook.Connections(1).ODBCConnection
 '…
 .CommandText = Join$(Array(s1 & s2 & s3 & s4 & s5 & s6 & s7 & s8 & s9 & s10 & s11 & s12 & s13 & s14 & s15 & s16 & s17 & s18 & s19 &s20)) 
 '…
End With